# Rails way to include functions used in several places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rails-3.1, before-save

I have a function (creation of a record in a table) that must be executed within before_save routines of models. What is the preferred way to do it?  I am in Rails 3.1.
A module in lib?
A class in lib?
application.rb?

Any example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module in `lib/`. Why a class if it's just a function? And don't clutter `application.rb`.

Comment: I added the module and a function with 
def self.functionName   is that correct?
In my model I added
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/<moduleName>"

How Can I invoke the function?

Comment: call ModuleName.functionName(), or alterantively, define without self, and include the module (hard to say which is cleaner without a clearer description of your exact problem)